# Firebase dependency isnt showing up?

Tags: java, firebase, gradle, dependencies, minecraft-forge

So I've tried adding Firebase dependency to my gradle project. But it doesn't seem to be working. It adds fine, there's no errors or anything and I can see the firebase jar in my Referenced Libraries. But whenever I try to import anything from it like `import google.com.firebase`, it doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong? These are the only imports I'm seeing.

[image]

This is my repositories thing in build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

This is my dependencies thing

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
}
```

So basically, the dependency adds correctly I think, it does show up on the Referenced libraries on my IDE but I don't know why I cannot access it?

[image]

Btw I'm not making an Android app, it's a mod for minecraft that uses forge gradle.

Also this is my gradle version: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because i used an dependency meant for android developers with the aar extensions so instead of using

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
```

In dependencies in build.gradle using this which is meant for the java thing works now.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.16.0'
```